# 10.3.3 miracles?

Tags: iphone, software-update, filesystem

So I recently upgraded from from 10.x.x to 10.3.3 (don't remember which exact version I had before). Everything is fine, but one thing caught my attention.
Before the update, I had 3 gigs of free storage. After, I suddenly have 34.8 gigs of free storage.

How is that possible? Is it just the update cleaning the device from all useless pieces of data (installation data/etc, I used to install and reinstall plenty of apps) or is it some APFS magic?

I personally believe that's a little bit of both.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can you confirm that you meant to say that your free space jumped from 3GB to 33GB (as opposed to 3.3GB)? While APFS is certainly optimised for flash storage etc, it's not going to explain a jump in free space in the order of 1000%. So, if your free space has in fact jumped from 3GB to 33GB then something else has happened, and you may need to edit your question to clarify how you updated and/or what storage space you're referring (e.g. Local v iCloud, etc)?

Comment: @Monomeeth Thanks! Yes I can confirm that my free space jumped from let's say around 3GB to 34.8 GB (as shown in iTunes). I updated the data in the post to make it less confusing for other folks. The update was performed by air. I'm referring to local storage. I will also try to check the size calculations for everything I store on my phone to make sure that it's not some kind of a glitch.

Comment: @Monomeeth I've checked the calculations and everything seems to be right.

Comment: Thanks for double checking and clarifying your question. FWIW, my guess is that either apps and/or media have been removed. It may be worth checking some of your settings in case your music hasn't synced (e.g. iCloud Music Library, etc).

Comment: @Monomeeth I had a backup of some media from my device and the strange thing is that everything seems to be fine. The counters are the same, nothing seems to be changed or removed on the device. Anyways, thank you for your participation, much appreciated! :-)

Comment: I also think that I'll have to download some kind of a large iOS game or hook up with test files to check whether it's a some kind of bug or not.

Comment: This isn't going to explain the massive difference but your device may have downloaded iOS updates onto itself and not installed them. Major updates are in the order of about 4-5GBs so if it failed a few times and have half downloaded files they may have contributed to space loss and when an update was finally completed iOS would of cleared that directory